# React JS - Uncaught TypeError: data?.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, rapidapi, shazam

I have just started coding in React, I am using it to code a music app. I tried to code along this tutorial https://youtu.be/I1cpb0tYV74?feature=shared. The only difference between mine and his is that used we used different API.

While coding I keep getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: data?.map is not a function.

I'm feeling a bit lost and could use some friendly advice. Can someone help me and let me know where I might be making mistakes?

Here my coding:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Error, Loader, SongCard } from '../components';
import { genres } from '../assets/constants';

import { useGetTopChartsQuery } from '../redux/services/shazamApi';

const Discover = () => {
    const { data, isFetching, error } = useGetTopChartsQuery();
    const genreTitle = 'Pop';

    console.log(data);

    return(
    <div className="flex flex-col">
        <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center sm:flex-row flex-col mt-4 mb-10">
            <h2 className="font-bold text-3xl text-white text-left">Discover {genreTitle}</h2>
            <select
            onChange={() => {}}
            value=""
            className='bg-black text-gray-300 p-3 text-sm rounded-lg outline-none sm:mt-0 mt-5'
            >
                {genres.map((genre) => <option key={genre.value} value={genre.value}>{genre.title}</option>)}
            </select>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-wrap sm:justify-start justify-center gap-8">
            {data?.map((song, i) => (
                <SongCard
                    key={song.key}
                    song={song}
                    data={data}
                    i={i}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Discover;
```

Here what the data looks like:

```
{
  "properties": {},
  "tracks": [
    {
      "layout": "5",
      "type": "MUSIC",
      "key": "673557639",
      "title": "Paint The Town Red",
      "subtitle": "Doja Cat",
      "share": {
        "subject": "Paint The Town Red - Doja Cat",
        "text": "Paint The Town Red by Doja Cat",
        "href": "https://www.shazam.com/track/673557639/paint-the-town-red",
        "image": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music116/v4/97/c7/f2/97c7f256-6db0-a45b-a786-f58dc928c970/196871404495.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",
        "twitter": "I used @Shazam to discover Paint The Town Red by Doja Cat.",
        "html": "https://www.shazam.com/snippets/email-share/673557639?lang=en-US&country=US",
        "avatar": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/AMCArtistImages116/v4/54/ba/99/54ba9945-5aae-bec7-a80c-188de630b37b/d62857dc-e8bd-41f6-b4d5-e368875c6044_ami-identity-7d4c30a95a90f129a834aecd444aa07a-2023-06-16T14-02-41.627Z_cropped.png/800x800cc.jpg",
        "snapchat": "https://www.shazam.com/partner/sc/track/673557639"
      },
      "images": {
        "background": "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/AMCArtistImages116/v4/54/ba/99/54ba9945-5aae-bec7-a80c-188de630b37b/d62857dc-e8bd-41f6-b4d5-e368875c6044_ami-identity-7d4c30a95a90f129a834aecd444aa07a-2023-06-16T14-02-41.627Z_cropped.png/800x800cc.jpg",
        "coverart": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music116/v4/97/c7/f2/97c7f256-6db0-a45b-a786-f58dc928c970/196871404495.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",
        "coverarthq": "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music116/v4/97/c7/f2/97c7f256-6db0-a45b-a786-f58dc928c970/196871404495.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",
        "joecolor": "b:ffffffp:050607s:1b1515t:373838q:494443"
      },
      "hub": {
        "type": "APPLEMUSIC",
        "image": "https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/applemusic.png",
        "actions": [
          {
            "name": "apple",
            "type": "applemusicplay",
            "id": "1704921697"
          },
          {
            "name": "apple",
            "type": "uri",
            "uri": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview116/v4/cd/87/0b/cd870b5f-c356-f761-e176-c45aba37eab1/mzaf_17565732451070337798.plus.aac.ep.m4a"
          }
        ],
        "options": [
          {
            "caption": "OPEN",
            "actions": [
              {
                "name": "hub:applemusic:deeplink",
                "type": "applemusicopen",
                "uri": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/paint-the-town-red/1704921687?i=1704921697&mttnagencyid=s2n&mttnsiteid=125115&mttn3pid=Apple-Shazam&mttnsub1=Shazam_web&mttnsub2=5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973&itscg=30201&app=music&itsct=Shazam_web"
              },
              {
                "name": "hub:applemusic:deeplink",
                "type": "uri",
                "uri": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/paint-the-town-red/1704921687?i=1704921697&mttnagencyid=s2n&mttnsiteid=125115&mttn3pid=Apple-Shazam&mttnsub1=Shazam_web&mttnsub2=5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973&itscg=30201&app=music&itsct=Shazam_web"
              }
            ],
            "beacondata": {
              "type": "open",
              "providername": "applemusic"
            },
            "image": "https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/overflow-open-option.png",
            "type": "open",
            "listcaption": "Open in Apple Music",
            "overflowimage": "https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/applemusic-overflow.png",
            "colouroverflowimage": false,
            "providername": "applemusic"
          }
        ],
        "explicit": true,
        "displayname": "APPLE MUSIC"
      },
      "artists": [
        {
          "alias": "doja-cat",
          "id": "42",
          "adamid": "830588310"
        }
      ],
      "url": "https://www.shazam.com/track/673557639/paint-the-town-red",
      "highlightsurls": {
        "artisthighlightsurl": "https://cdn.shazam.com/video/v3/en-US/US/web/830588310/highlights?affiliate=mttnagencyid%3Ds2n%26mttnsiteid%3D125115%26mttn3pid%3DApple-Shazam%26mttnsub1%3DShazam_web%26mttnsub2%3D5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973%26itscg%3D30201%26app%3Dmusic%26itsct%3DShazam_web&videoIdToFilter=1701008023",
        "trackhighlighturl": "https://cdn.shazam.com/video/v3/en-US/US/web/highlights/1701008023?affiliate=mttnagencyid%3Ds2n%26mttnsiteid%3D125115%26mttn3pid%3DApple-Shazam%26mttnsub1%3DShazam_web%26mttnsub2%3D5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973%26itscg%3D30201%26app%3Dmusic%26itsct%3DShazam_web"
      },
      "properties": {}
    },
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data?.map is not a function
    at Discover (Discover.jsx:27:20)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:20)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:20)
```

It's supposed to show the main page but it just show a white background.

Comment: Add `useGetTopChartsQuery` definition.

Comment: map() is a function if `data` is an Array.  you haven't shown us what kind of object `data` is but it sure looks like it's not an array.

Comment: You should additionally check if data has a map method, `data?.map(map fn)` becomes `data?.map?.(map fn)`

Comment: The data is from Shazam Api. I used the Rapid Api music fetching to fetch the music data.